# XML data to listbox

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a XML file with data about servers in it. The country and the IP of the server.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<servers>

<server>
   <location>Belgium</location>
   <ip>192.168.0.1</ip>
</server>

<server>
    <location>The Netherlands</location>
    <ip>127.0.0.6</ip>
</server>

</servers>
```

I want to add the location name + IP + ping to the IP in one line in the listbox and so on for every server.

This is my code so far but it only tells me the location. I have no idea how to append the IP and ping to the IP.

```
Dim xr As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create("http://127.0.0.1/servers.xml")
Do While xr.Read()
    If xr.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element AndAlso xr.Name = "location" Then
        lsbServers.Items.Add(xr.ReadElementString)
    Else
        xr.Read()
    End If
Loop
```

How do I add the IP and ping to the IP to the location in the listbox?

Comment: Did you check [Ping Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to append the IP + ping to the IP to the location in the listbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `XmlReader` class is useful for some tasks, but, by design, it only inspects one node at a time.  In a case like this, where you need to access multiple elements at once in a random-access fashion, it would be easier to use either the `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` class.  For instance:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("http://127.0.0.1/servers.xml")
For Each serverNode As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("/servers/server")
    Dim location As String = serverNode.SelectSingleNode("location").InnerText
    Dim ip As String = serverNode.SelectSingleNode("ip").InnerText
Next
```

Or,

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("http://127.0.0.1/servers.xml")
For Each serverElement As XElement In doc.<servers>.<server>
    Dim location As String = serverElement.<location>.Value
    Dim ip As String = serverElement.<ip>.Value
Next
```

Then, when you add the item to the list box, you can concatenate the data into a string and/or format it however you like, for instance:

```
lsbServers.Items.Add(location & " - " & ip))
```

Or:

```
lsbServers.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", location, ip))
```

However, when you have multiple data per item in the list, you may want to consider using a control which supports showing multiple columns of data, such as the `ListView` or `DataGrid` controls.  (In order to show columns in the `ListView` control, you need to set the `View` property to `Details`).

Answer (score 1):

I would use LINQ to XML:

```
Dim xr As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create("http://127.0.0.1/servers.xml")
Dim xDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(xr)

For Each server as XElement In xDoc.Root.Elements("server")
    Dim location As String = CType(server.Element("location"), String)
    Dim ip As String = CType(server.Element("ip"), String)
    ' your ping logic goes here '
    Dim ping as String = GetPing(ip)

    lsbServers.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}", location, ip, ping))
Next
```